# Failure to bundle ec2 - how to get more information?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a ec2 bundle.
I'm running the command:

```
ec2-bundle-vol -r $arch -d /mnt -p $prefix -u $AWS_USER_ID -k ~/.ec2/pk-*.pem -c ~/.ec2/cert-*.pem -s 10240 -e /mnt,/vol/mysql_data  --debug
```

It ends with error "execution failed" (how informative!)

```
ERROR: execution failed: "
rsync -rlpgoD -t -r -S -l --exclude /sys --exclude /proc --exclude /dev/pts --exclude /dev --exclude /media --exclude /mnt --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
--exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/z25_persistent-net.rules --exclude /mnt --exclude /vol/mysql_data --exclude /mnt/img-mnt -X /* /mnt/img-mnt 2>&1 > /dev/null"
```

with debug flag it shows also:

```
#<RuntimeError: execution failed: "rsync -rlpgoD -t -r -S -l --exclude /sys --exclude /proc --exclude /dev/pts --exclude /dev --exclude /media --exclude /mnt --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules --exclude /etc/udev/rules.d/z25_persistent-net.rules --exclude /mnt --exclude  /vol/mysql_data  --exclude /mnt/img-mnt -X /* /mnt/img-mnt 2>&1 > /dev/null">
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:244:in `execute'   
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:156:in `copy_rec'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/ec2/platform/linux/image.rb:84:in `make'
/usr/lib/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:151:in `bundle_vol'
/usr/lib/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:193:in `main'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/ec2/amitools/tool_base.rb:201:in `run'
/usr/lib/site_ruby/ec2/amitools/bundlevol.rb:201
```

Which tells me the error starts somewhere at VolBundler run() method (guessing, I don't know ruby).

Anyone has any idea what the error is?  or how can I get more information?

Comment: I am getting the same error. When I checked the size of image created in /tmp folder it is 10GB. So it is exceeding the max size of the image

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you do not exceed 10 GB Limit for an AWS bundle. Exclude all extra directories.

Also if you are doing bundling from within a running instance, make sure that you got all unnecessary services (like sendmail) stopped.